# Setting up paypal with laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, paypal, config

I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BsF_aSCd0I try and set up paypal

```
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            
            var theCurrency=$('#currency').val().toUpperCase()
                return fetch('/paypal/order/create/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({price:donationAmount,currency:theCurrency,description:"a description"}),
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'X_CSRF_Token': $('[name="_token"]').val()
                }
                }).then(function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    console.log(orderData);

                    return orderData.orderId;
                });
            },

            // Call your server to finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/paypal/order/capture/', {
                    method: 'post',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        orderId:data.orderID,
                })
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    // Three cases to handle:
                    //   (1) Recoverable INSTRUMENT_DECLINED -> call actions.restart()
                    //   (2) Other non-recoverable errors -> Show a failure message
                    //   (3) Successful transaction -> Show confirmation or thank you

                    // This example reads a v2/checkout/orders capture response, propagated from the server
                    // You could use a different API or structure for your 'orderData'
                    var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];

                    if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                        return actions.restart(); // Recoverable state, per:
                        // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/
                    }

                    if (errorDetail) {
                        var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
                        if (errorDetail.description) msg += '\n\n' + errorDetail.description;
                        if (orderData.debug_id) msg += ' (' + orderData.debug_id + ')';
                        return alert(msg); // Show a failure message (try to avoid alerts in production environments)
                    }

                    // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                    console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                    var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                    alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

                });
            }

        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

DonationsController:

```
` public function handlePaypalCreate(Request $request)
{
    Log::info($request->getContent());
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);
    $provider = \PayPal::setProvider();
    $provider->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken();
    $provider->setAccessToken($token);
    $order = $provider->createOrder(['intent' => 'CAPTURE','purchase_units' => ['amount' => ['currency_code' => $data->currency,'value' => $data->price],'description' => $data->description]]);
    return response()->json($order);
}
public function handlePaypalCapture(Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);
    $orderId=$data->orderId;
    $provider = PayPal::setProvider();
    $provider->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken();
    $provider->setAccessToken($token);
    return $provider->capturePaypalOrder($token);
}
```

routes

```
Route::post('paypal/order/create',[DonationsController::class, 'handlePaypalCreate']);
Route::post('paypal/order/capture',[DonationsController::class, 'handlePaypalCapture']);
```

I added the requires and publish

composer require srmklive/paypal:
php artisan vendor:publish --provider "Srmklive\PayPal\Providers\PayPalServiceProvider"
and
paypal .env and config

```
<?php
return [
    'mode'    => env('PAYPAL_MODE', 'sandbox'), // Can only be 'sandbox' Or 'live'. If empty or invalid, 'live' will be used.
    'sandbox' => [
        'client_id'         => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID', ''),
        'client_secret'     => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_SECRET', ''),
        'app_id'            => 'APP-80W284485P519543T',
    ],
    'live' => [
        'client_id'         => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_CLIENT_ID', ''),
        'client_secret'     => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_CLIENT_SECRET', ''),
        'app_id'            => '',
    ],

    'payment_action' => env('PAYPAL_PAYMENT_ACTION', 'Sale'), // Can only be 'Sale', 'Authorization' or 'Order'
    'currency'       => env('PAYPAL_CURRENCY', 'USD'),
    'notify_url'     => env('PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL', ''), // Change this accordingly for your application.
    'locale'         => env('PAYPAL_LOCALE', 'en_US'), // force gateway language  i.e. it_IT, es_ES, en_US ... (for express checkout only)
    'validate_ssl'   => env('PAYPAL_VALIDATE_SSL', true), // Validate SSL when creating api client.
];
```

this doesn't open the window but throws a json parse error or missing an ID error in some cases when not fullscreaned on localhost.

Please explain what I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Your server route, `/paypal/order/create/` , is not successfully creating a PayPal order and/or not returning a JSON object with an ID to the calling JS.

You must debug this at runtime. Opening your browser's Dev Tools and going to the Network tab can serve as a starting point, but the underlying issue may be server-side in your PHP and have to be debugged there -- invalid REST API credentials, network issues, SSL verification problems, and so on are just some of the possible error scenarios.

Comment: after a lot of debugging this is what came up when I added an Log::info to the srmklive library  [2022-07-22 17:05:38] local.INFO: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token . So like I need an ssl lock on my localhost to test?

Comment: Update your root certificate authority bundle that's used to trust the signers of SSL/TLS certificates; you can download a current one here https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: I have extension=openssl  curl.cainfo ="C:\wamp643\bin\php\php8.1.0\extras\ssl\cacert.pem" openssl.cafile="C:\wamp643\bin\php\php8.1.0\extras\ssl\cacert.pem" in php.ini  and LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so uncommented in httpd.conf and I downloaded the file from the link you gave me and replaced my old cacert with that one. restarted wamp server and laravel server. Same error wamp643 is the right folder... don't ask.